# i18next serbian latin characters

Tags: jquery, html, i18next

I have static website written purely in html (Jquery+Bootstrap).
Then, I wanted to add some localization (only two languages: Serbian and English).
I succeed with [i18next](http://i18next.github.io/i18next/pages/sample.html?setLng=en-US) plugin.

It works, but when I translate to Serbian language, some special characters are ugly (bold char and not properly sized). Chars are (in Serbian keyboard): š,đ,č,ć. See [image: here]

Alternative link to image: [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w38otb2rb2vh127/i18nextProblem.PNG?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, not all fonts has serbian latin specific characters.
The best practice is to visit [fonts.google.com](http://fonts.google.com) and to test it on some desired font.
I choose Roboto font, and it has correct sized chars.

Cheers!